# Inducing a Permutation

Tags: permutations

I'm trying to understand the following, from the OEIS, sequence [A294673](http://oeis.org/A294673):

> a(n) is equal to the order of multiplication-by-2 acting on the set of non-zero elements in (Z/(4n+3)Z), modulo the action of +-1.  To be precise, identify i=1,2,...,2*n+1 with the odd representatives J=1,3,...,4*n+1 of this set, via the map J = 2*i-1. It is not hard to show that the induced permutation on the set of J values is given on integer representatives by J -> (4*n+3+J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is even and J -> (4*n+3-J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is odd. It follows that this induces the permutation J -> +-J/2 (mod 4*n+3), from which we immediately see that the order is as stated.
>
> Note that the order of 2 acting on (Z/(4n+3)Z)/{+-1} is the same as the order of either 2 or -2 acting on (Z/(4n+3)Z), depending on which of these is a quadratic residue modulo 4n+3.  Thus an equivalent (and often easier) way to compute a(n) is as the order of -2*(-1)^n acting on (Z/(4n+3)Z).
>
> Among other things, the lower and upper bounds log_2(n) + 2 < a(n) <= 2*n+1 follow immediately.

...but I can't figure out what inducing a permutation means - can't understand it well enough to follow the presentation.

I have a feeling that it's pretty simple, but I haven't been able to find a simple presentation of it; everything I find assumes that the reader knows what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $n=3$, so that we're working over $\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z$.

Then the possible remainders modulo $15$, up to sign, are:
$$
    0, \pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \pm4, \pm5, \pm6,\pm7
$$
and multiplying them by $2$ gives
$$
    0, \pm2, \pm4, \pm6, \pm7, \pm5, \pm3, \pm1.
$$
(For example, $\pm6 \times 2 = \pm 12 \equiv \pm 3 \pmod {15}$.)

The permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ that this operation *induces* is the bijective function $f$ from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ for which $f(x)=y$ whenever $\pm x \times 2 \equiv \pm y \pmod{15}$. (For example, $f(6) = 3$.)

In this case, we can specify this permutation as the list
$$
    f(1)=2,\, f(2)=4,\, f(3)=6,\, f(4)=7,\, f(5)=5,\, f(6)=3,\, f(7)=1
$$
or in one-line notation as $2\,4\,6\,7\,5\,3\,1$.

The order of this permutation is $4$, because

- $f(f(f(f(x)))) = x$ for all inputs $x$: applying $f$ $4$ times always returns you to where you started,
- $4$ is the least positive integer for which it's true. (It's also true for all multiples of $4$.)

So in the sequence [A294673](http://oeis.org/A294673), $a(3) = 4$.

Comment: a few:  1. i would've said either n=3 or 4n+3=19, but no problem.

Comment: 2. so it's *2 that induces the permutation.  great!

Comment: 3. why is it that "we immediately see that the order is as stated."?  i see that it is, but i wouldn't w/o working out p(p(...))

Comment: 4.  here, J = 2*i-1 - not 2*i -- but again, no problem - unless im missing something

Comment: 5. "J -> (4*n+3+J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is even and J -> (4*n+3-J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is odd." is just the algebraic generalization of your concrete example (?)

Comment: 6. just before that, he says "induced permutation", but then he moves on to "this induces the permutation J -> +-J/2 (mod 4*n+3)" (a different p()).  not obvious to me - but i guess if one works out the table, one sees that (>)

Comment: 7. "the order of 2 acting on (Z/(4n+3)Z)/{+-1} is the same as the order of either 2 or -2 acting on (Z/(4n+3)Z)".  is that supposed to be obvious?

Comment: 8. "depending on which of these is a quadratic residue modulo 4n+3".  why is qquad. res. relevant here?  could you concretize?

Comment: 9. he switches from talking about induced permutations to talking about their orders.  that confused me when i was trying to follow this by working out concretes for everything -- but re the orders:  it's not obvious to me why the order that's desired at the beginning has to be the same as  the one at the end

Comment: 00.  sorry for the 11 comments, but i thought i'd better make all my remauining questions as clear and separate as possible

Comment: I've fixed the n=3 vs n=4 issue. I think the remaining bit that's confusing is that where I'm listing the representatives in the order $\pm1, \pm2, \pm3, \dots$ the OEIS comment is listing them in the order $\pm1, \pm3, \pm5, \dots$ (that's the J=2*i-1 bit) so that the permutation there is a different one, but whose order is the same. (And in fact it's the same permutation up to relabeling.)

Comment: Thanks, Misha.  i upvoted it, but mine doesn't count.  i'll go over it sgain now; maybe i can answer some of my own still-remaining questions

Comment: The original says "identify i=1,2,...,2*n+1 with the odd representatives J=1,3,...,4*n+1 of this set, via the map J = 2*i-1. It is not hard to show that the induced permutation on the set of J values is given on integer representatives by J -> (4*n+3+J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is even and J -> (4*n+3-J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is odd.",     i don't see it.  i think i made a table that's consistent with that, but isn't he talking about a more-direct way of "seeing it"?

Comment: i((j+1)/2)  J  n  J->
1           1  2   5 or 6 
2           3      4    7   
3           5      3    8               
4           7      2    9
5           9      1   10 is the table i get from "It is not hard to show that the induced permutation on the set of J values is given on integer representatives by J -> (4*n+3+J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is even and J -> (4*n+3-J)/2 if i=(J+1)/2 is odd.".  i don't think that's right.

Comment: too bad this won't let me use multiple lines; if it did, the above would be readable

Comment: n=2/  /i((j+1)/2) J  J->1           1   5/  /2           3   4/   /3           5   3/   /4       7   2/   /5           8   1////////////////what does that have to do with anything?

Comment: 2b:  ***: but what's the rationale for multiplying by two in the first place? :***